# Kafka consumer restart when it is reading from beginning of topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new to Kafka .

Lets say I have one kafka topic topoic1(replicationfactor=1,partitions=1) and one consumer(java process) reading(readfrombegining/earliest) from kafka topic1 . Consumer is running fine for some time and later for some reason it got hung and killed by admin.

So if I Restart the consumer it will read from beginning again leading to data duplication So how to handle this usecase ?

NOTE: I am aware that if the consumer code written as to read from latest then we will not get duplicated data. Other than this is there in solution ?

Comment: You can't have 0 replicas or 0 partitions...

Answer (score 0):

Consumers will only reset from the beginning when `auto.offset.reset=earliest`, and

- you have auto commits disabled + don't manually commit offsets
- **or** don't manually seek the consumer upon startup; i.e. you can track offsets externally from Kafka